# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, ajax

Пытаюсь отправить форму через AJAX.
При отправке получаю ошибку:

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.

Мой код:

```
 <form  id="contact-form" class="row" onsubmit="submit()" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                        <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4 r-full-width">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" required name="firstname" placeholder="Имя" id="firstname">
                                <i class="bar"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4 r-full-width">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="email" parsley-error required parsley-type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" id="email">
                                <i class="bar"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4 r-full-width">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input data-parsley-type="number" type="text" required name="phonenumber" placeholder="Номер телефона" id="phonenumber">
                                <i class="bar"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <textarea rows="3" name="comment" id="comment"></textarea>
                                <label class="control-label">Дополнительная информация:</label><i class="bar"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                            <input type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light" style="width: 100%; background-color: #374886;" value="Отправить">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @*<label>Название курса:</label>*@
                            <input type="hidden" parsley-error required="" id="coursein" name="coursename" value="">
                        </div>
                    </form>
    $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#submit').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var form = {
                    firstname: $('#firstname').val(),
                    email: $('#email').val(),
                    phonenumber: $('#phonenumber').val(),
                    comment: $('#comment')

                }

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/ru/Feedback',
                    data: form ,
                    success: function (msg) {
                        alert("Ваша заявка успешно отправлена!")
                    },
                    error: function(result) {
                    alert("WRONG")
                }
        })
        })
        })
```

Comment: Действительно. Вместо $('#comment') должно быть $('#comment').val()

Answer (score 2):

Сериализация циклических ссылок:

```
comment: $('#comment').val()
```